# How do I map values from a dictionary to a new column in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I was trying to map the values to a new column in my pyspark df

```
dict = {'443368995': 0, '667593514': 1, '940995585': 2, '880811536': 3, '174590194': 4}

I am reading a csv which has following data -
+--------------------+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+----------+---------+
|              Region|         Country| ItemType|SalesChannel|OrderPriority| OrderDate|  OrderID|
+--------------------+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+----------+---------+
|  Sub-Saharan Africa|    South Africa|   Fruits|     Offline|            M| 7/27/2012|443368995|
|Middle East and N...|         Morocco|  Clothes|      Online|            M| 9/14/2013|667593514|
|Australia and Oce...|Papua New Guinea|     Meat|     Offline|            M| 5/15/2015|940995585|
|  Sub-Saharan Africa|        Djibouti|  Clothes|     Offline|            H| 5/17/2017|880811536|
|              Europe|        Slovakia|Beverages|     Offline|            L|10/26/2016|174590194|
+--------------------+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

Below is an addiontal column that I want to add based on some decision using the dictionary above -

```
+---------+
| SomeFlag|
+---------+
|        Y|
|        N|
|        Y|
|        Y|
|        Y|
+---------+
```

Here is my code that I have tried ==>

```
df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("sample.csv")
def my_mapp_fn(checkcol, dict1):
     print(col(checkcol))
     print(key)
     return coalesce(*[when(col(checkcol) == key, lit(value)) for key, value in d.items()])

new_df = df.withColumn("SomeFlag", my_mapp_fn(dict, col('OrderId')))
```

I am getting below error ==>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in my_mapp_fn
  File "C:\BigData\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 106, in col
    return _invoke_function("col", col)
  File "C:\BigData\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 58, in _invoke_function
    return Column(jf(*args))
  File "C:\BigData\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1296, in __call__
  File "C:\BigData\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1260, in _build_args
  File "C:\BigData\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1247, in _get_args
  File "C:\BigData\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_collections.py", line 510, in convert
  File "C:\BigData\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\column.py", line 460, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to map dict and create column based on that you could write:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dict_data = {'443368995': '0', '667593514': '1', '940995585': '2', '880811536': '3', '174590194': '4'}

d = [
    ("M", '443368995'),
    ("M", '667593514'),
    ("M", '940995585'),
    ("H", '880811536'),
    ("L", '174590194'),
    
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d,['OrderPriority','OrderID'])
df.show()

# output
+-------------+---------+
|OrderPriority|  OrderID|
+-------------+---------+
|            M|443368995|
|            M|667593514|
|            M|940995585|
|            H|880811536|
|            L|174590194|
+-------------+---------+


(
    df
    .withColumn("MapOrderID", F.col("OrderID"))
    .replace(to_replace=dict_data, subset=["MapOrderID"])
    .show()
)

# output
+-------------+---------+----------+
|OrderPriority|  OrderID|MapOrderID|
+-------------+---------+----------+
|            M|443368995|         0|
|            M|667593514|         1|
|            M|940995585|         2|
|            H|880811536|         3|
|            L|174590194|         4|
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

And you can apply when/otherwise on newly created column:

```
(
    df
    .withColumn("MapOrderID", F.col("OrderID"))
    .replace(to_replace=dict_data, subset=["MapOrderID"])
    .withColumn("MapOrderID", 
                F.when(F.col("MapOrderID") == "2", "Ok").otherwise("Not Ok")
               )
    .show()
)

# output
+-------------+---------+----------+
|OrderPriority|  OrderID|MapOrderID|
+-------------+---------+----------+
|            M|443368995|    Not Ok|
|            M|667593514|    Not Ok|
|            M|940995585|        Ok|
|            H|880811536|    Not Ok|
|            L|174590194|    Not Ok|
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

Important is that key/value in dict has to be the same type.
It means that if ID you want to map is string, value 1/2/3 should be string too, otherwise you can have error:

```
ValueError: Mixed type replacements are not supported
```

Comment: But rather doing this, I can just then create a new df with OrderID and SomeFlag and join with the original. I was looking for a udf or pyspark functions level solution so that I dont have to create a new df